# How to make x button at searcView avaible, even if search field is empty?

Tags: java, android

I can get x button just when i start to write something at search field. But i need to get it anytime. The idea is: if field isn't empty - clear it. Else - close the fragment. Thanks for help:)

```
public class AddNewCardFragment extends Fragment
    implements SearchView.OnCloseListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_card_fragment, container, false);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    setupSearchView();
    mSearchView.setQuery(selectedFromList, false);
    return v;
}

private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Enter location");
}

@Override
public boolean onClose() {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    cityName = query;
    mMainFragment.setLocationsList(new CityLocation(cityName ,mMainFragment.idCounter++, getActivity()));
    fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans.replace(R.id.main_layout, mMainFragment);
    fTrans.commit();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: If this Java ? Then maybe add the tag...

Comment: Yes. Could you give more informative answer? I,m a new at android.

Comment: Well then, do add that tag if you want java guys to look at your question... (click the "edit" link at the bottom). And no, can't answer, I'm just reviewing questions, have no idea what you're talking about ;-)